# How to say "It is likely that I will be at the party tomorrow"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How can I say "It is likely that I will be at the party tomorrow"?

> Es ist wahrscheinlich, dass ich morgen bei der Party sein werde.

Is the use of "wahrscheinlich" correct here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suggestion is not wrong, if a bit formal. If you start your sentence with "Wahrscheinlich" it sounds quite a bit more natural:

> Wahrscheinlich werde ich morgen auf die Party gehen.
>   Vermutlich bin ich morgen auf der Party.

Comment: Interestingly, English is rather clumsy here, because `likely` is an adjective without corresponding adverb.